Guest user "Log out"
so i know guest users are not technically logged in but they do use up licences. Experience cloud sites include 100 free guest user licences. 
We want to have a Experience cloud sites that is only for guest users and we do not want to use Site.com. If there are only 100 guest user licences, i assume that when 101 user visits the site symoltaniously, the 101th would get some sort of 'not accessable' message. 
So what i am wondering is, can we remove a licence from aguest user. For example, a user has had the site open for 2 hours and has been inactive the whole time. Can i log this user out somehow to free up their licence?
Thanks for you help.

I think you are misunderstanding what how Guest Site User works. The Guest Site User is a way to setup the permissions for anyone accessing that particular site (There is one Guest User Profile for each site - so 100 Sites means there are 100 Users)
As the answer below states, the number of page views that site can provide is based on the edition - not GSU licenses

If you're going to create a new Digital Experience (Setup > Digital Experiences > All Sites > New) you don't have to worry about guest user licences. Let me quote the documentation about Experience Cloud licenses:

Are guest users counted against my licenses?
Not at all! Unauthenticated or guest users who access your Experience Cloud site don’t use up any of your external licenses.
Here are the page view limits for guest users, based on your Salesforce edition. [...]




Salesforce Edition
Number of Page Views




Enterprise Edition
500,000/month


Unlimited Edition
One million/month




Thank you. This is very helpful. However it seems to contradict what I read in the link below:  For Salesforce sites, Enterprise, Unlimited, and Performance Editions come with 100 Guest User licenses. Developer Edition comes with one Guest User license. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_sites.htm&type=5

@Dane Sites and Experience Cloud are not the same, that's why they have different limits. You could read about some difference between them here and here. By the way, here's the licenses available in an org that has a working Digital Experience used by Guest Users too

@Dane A license allows a user to be active. That says nothing about how many simultaneous logins a user can have. Try opening Chrome and Firefox, and log in to Salesforce on both. You'll have two sessions, but your user will still only be using one license.

@sfdcfox how many concurrent/simultaneous logins are allowed for a experience cloud site - guest user ?
